# Is this a sign of a harddrive failure or a software problem

Tags: ssd, syslog

I'm running a Kubuntu 20.04.2 on a Thinkpad T460 with a Samsung 2.5 inch SSD MZ7LN512HMJP - about 4 years old, got the machine pre-owned.

Once in a while there is a block of zeros in the syslog (Snow is the name of the machine named after a Spocks Beard album)

```
0000d28c  0a 46 65 62 20 31 31 20  31 32 3a 32 37 3a 32 34  |.Feb 11 12:27:24|
0000d29c  20 53 6e 6f 77 20 73 79  73 74 65 6d 64 5b 31 5d  | Snow systemd[1]|
0000d2ac  3a 20 75 6e 61 74 74 65  6e 64 65 64 2d 75 70 67  |: unattended-upg|
0000d2bc  72 61 64 65 73 2e 73 65  72 76 69 63 65 3a 20 53  |rades.service: S|
0000d2cc  75 63 63 65 65 64 65 64  2e 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ucceeded........|
0000d2dc  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0000dffc  00 00 00 00 46 65 62 20  31 31 20 31 32 3a 32 37  |....Feb 11 12:27|
0000e00c  3a 35 34 20 53 6e 6f 77  20 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 3a  |:54 Snow kernel:|
0000e01c  20 5b 20 20 20 20 30 2e  30 30 30 30 30 30 5d 20  | [    0.000000] |
0000e02c  6d 69 63 72 6f 63 6f 64  65 3a 20 6d              |microcode: m|
0000e038
```

This error leads to a reboot...

All smartctl-Tests (short, long, offline) end up with no error. The drive has 8400 hours and 22680 LBA written. fsck runs and that's it.

What do you think? Replace the ssd or is this a software problem that can be fixed?

EDIT: Unattended Upgrades are off (or am I wrong, I've never experienced that):

```
uwe@Snow:~$ grep Reboot /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
// when Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot is set to true
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "true";
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Comment: I don't see any error there.  Sometimes a file will fill with zeros to fill the rest of the block if the file itself isn't large enough to fill the block.  However, I see that you have unattended upgrades turned on and when it finishes upgrading if a restart is required, i.e. kernel update, the system rebooted like it should have.

Comment: Let's test that: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316394/edit) to show the complete output of `grep Reboot /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`